# Best way to monitor a file for new entries

Tags: bash, scripting

I constantly pull the log files from a server every minute using an FTP connection (only option).

I have a script that runs after and sorts all like file names into separate folders.  login logs go to login, admin logs go to admin, etc.  After they are moved, it merges all files together into a master log file for each like folder.

I am trying to monitor a log for new entries and post the login using a webhook.  However, since the file is always a new file, it posts all entries in the log every time someone logs in and every minute due to being a new file.

How do I accomplish combining the files using append instead of creating a new file all the time.

Here is my merge script:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
folder=/storage/downloads/ftp/archives

cat $folder/login/login_*.log | sort -n > $folder/all-logins.log
cat $folder/admin/admin_*.log | sort -n > $folder/all-admins.log
```

Here is my monitoring script recently corrected from here.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
tail -F /storage/downloads/ftp/all-logins.log |\
  while IFS=':(' read -r date x user x; do 
    echo "$user logged in at $date"
    if [ $? = 0 ]
     then
      curl -sfSL -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"content\":\"$user logged in at $date\"}" "url"
    fi
    done
exit
```

Comment: Take a look at [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=why&lang=en)

Comment: I will try.  I Franken-scripted the others based on combining searches online with no knowledge of it.